# Baked Raisin Cinnamon Bread and shipping

Tags: bread

I have been baking and selling breads and rolls this year locally. My question is can I freeze the bread prior to shipping or would it make bread soggy during shipping?  I am mailing from Texas to New York

Comment: Are you planning to ship the frozen bread?

Answer (score 2):

If the bread wasn't soggy before freezing, it won't be when it thaws. Properly sealed, items that are frozen don't absorb more moisture than they already contain.

At room temperature, a loaf of bread will thaw rather quickly, depending on the size and thickness of the loaf. At most, it would take about 3-4 hours to completely defrost, so freezing your product before shipping wouldn't be of much value.

Instead, consider how best to package it to keep it from drying out, or being damaged. Wrap it first in paper, then in plastic. Put it in a sturdy box, larger than the loaf and with enough extra space so that you can insert padding material (e.g., air pillows, bio-degradable peanuts) so that it doesn't move around. And send it overnight or priority, so that it's delivered within several days.